Connection pool manager in pytest selenium
today while creating a fixture for capturing a screenshot i encountered a warning which is

WARNING  urllib3.connectionpool:connectionpool.py:329 Connection pool is full, discarding connection: localhost. Connection pool size: 1

this might be because I was using the request library can anyone help me out to increase the pool limit as well tips to integrate it with my code
the fixture is for capturing the screenshot whenever the URL is changed

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
